# Unable to view SSRS reports in Crome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reporting-services, report, overflow

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
I know that its a common bug, and I tried to follow common procedure to fix it. 
In the file "ReportingServices.js" I copy-paste this code.

```
function pageLoad() {
    var element = document.getElementById("ctl31_ctl10");
    if (element)
    {
        element.style.overflow = "visible";
    }
}
```

But still no success. 
I also tried CSS file and added this code:

```
/**************CHROME BUG FIX*****************/
div#ctl31_ctl09,
div#ctl31_ctl10
{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
/*********************************************/
```

But still nothing. 
It works if I manually change `overflow` to `visible`.
[image]

But how can I always keep that way? 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Per your image the control's DIV Id is "ct132_ct109".  Your CSS file is for "div#ctl31_ctl09" and "div#ctl31_ctl10".  Try adding "div#ctl32_ctl09" to the CSS file and see what happens.